# Create date - Carbon in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I'm starting to read about `Carbon` and can't seem to figure out how to create a `carbon date`.

In the docs is says you can;

> `Carbon::createFromDate($year, $month, $day, $tz);
>   Carbon::createFromTime($hour, $minute, $second, $tz);
>   Carbon::create($year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute, $second, $tz);`

But what if I just recieve a `date` like `2016-01-23`? Do I have to strip out each part and feed it to `carbon` before I can create a `carbon` date? or maybe I receive `time` like `11:53:20`??

I'm dealing with dynamic dates and time and writing code to separate parts of time or date doesn't feel right.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can use one of two ways of creating a Carbon instance from that date string:

**1.** Create a new instance and pass the string to the constructor:

```
// From a datetime string
$datetime = new Carbon('2016-01-23 11:53:20');

// From a date string
$date = new Carbon('2016-01-23');

// From a time string
$time = new Carbon('11:53:20');
```

**2.** Use the `createFromFormat` method:

```
// From a datetime string
$datetime = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2016-01-23 11:53:20');

// From a date string
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2016-01-23');

// From a time string
$time = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', '11:53:20');
```

The Carbon class is just extending the PHP [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/ro/class.datetime.php) class, which means that you can use all the same methods including the same [constructor](http://php.net/manual/ro/datetime.construct.php) parameters or the [`createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/ro/datetime.createfromformat.php) method.

Comment: Can I use option 1 with time as well?

Comment: Sure you can. The constructor accepts any date and/or time string that has a valid format according to the [Supported Date and Time Formats](http://php.net/manual/ro/datetime.formats.php) Documentation. So it will work with a timestamp like this `11:53:20` as well.

Comment: Thanks for the help as always. Does `carbon` have any methods of rounding up? or how can I round up with `carbon` after I've added minutes etc

Comment: Could you provide an example of the starting value and the value you wanted it rounded to?

Comment: Any time value really. Like `'11:53:20'`... I would want to round up to the nearest `5` so to `'11:55:00'` for example. In my old code I was using `ceil`

Comment: Nope, Carbon doesn't implement that sort of logic.