# Parse complex string to carbon date

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I am using `Laravel Framework 6.16.0` and want to parse a date with carbon `"Dec 14 02:04 PM"`:

```
$fillingDate = "Dec 14 02:04 PM";
$filling_Date = Carbon::parse($fillingDate, 'UTC'); 
// result is only a string "Dec 14 02:04 PM"
```

When using the above structure I only get the string back. However, I would like to get a Carbon object that gets then formatted to `->format('Y-m-d')`.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: `Carbon::parse()` should either return a Carbon instance or an "InvalidFormatException".   `Carbon::parse($fillingDate, 'UTC')` should give back a full Carbon instance

Comment: Did you do `dd($filling_date)`? It _is_ a Carbon instance in my code: `=> Carbon\Carbon @1607954640 {#3300 date: 2020-12-14 14:04:00.0 UTC (+00:00), timezone_type: 3, timezone: "UTC", }`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How could i create carbon object from given datetime structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41236385/how-could-i-create-carbon-object-from-given-datetime-structure)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34971082/create-date-carbon-in-laravel

Answer (score 3):

You can create carbon object from a string by calling the static function `createFromFormat`.

In this case:

```
$fillingDate = "Dec 14 02:04 PM";    
$filling_Date = Carbon::createFromFormat("M d g:i A", $fillingDate)
```

Format characters explained:

- M - A short textual representation of a month, three letters
- d - Day of the month, 2 digits with leading zeros
- g - 12-hour format of an hour without leading zeros
- i - Minutes with leading zeros
- A - Uppercase Ante meridiem and Post meridiem

More about format characters: [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)